# How to set properties in the same class?

Tags: c#, properties

I am having difficulties setting the values of certain variables. In my GameController class I want the user to input the number of players. I then want my code to create an array that will hold scores for each of the players.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Game GC = new Game();
        GC.GetNumberPlayers();
        GC.SetInitialScores();
    }               
}

class Game
{
    private int players;
    private int[] scores;
    private string[] playerNames;

    public int Players
    {
        get { return players; }
        set { players = value; ; }
    }

    public int[] Scores
    {
        get { return scores; }
        set { scores = value; }
    }

    public int GetNumberPlayers()
    {
        string playersString;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter number of players");
        playersString = Console.ReadLine();
        Int32.TryParse(playersString, out players);
        return players;
    }

    public int[] SetInitialScores()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < players; i++ )
        {
            scores[i] = 0;
        }
        return scores;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't think this will have much of an effect but you have an extra`;` in your `Players set{}`

Comment: @Ben back in the K&R C days a lone semicolon was no-op.  I believe C# has maintained this.

Comment: Not really relevant, but shadowing the global `GC` static class members (which can be used to manipulate the garbage collector) is not perhaps the wisest naming choice.

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

`GetNumberPlayers` returns an `integer`, you are not doing anything with it due to calling it as `GC.GetNumberPlayers();`

If you wanted to have the value of `GetNumberPlayers()`, you would need to call it like `int numPlayers = GC.GetNumberPlayers();`

Since you are setting `players` value in your try parse, there is not really any reason to return it since you're using it only internally (or if you were using it externally by assigning it to a variable as in above)

The same holds true for your function `SetInitialScores`, with an additional problem.  Arrays need their length to be declared as a part of their initialization.  You are not initializing the array at all, and are thus running into a run time error.  You could initialize the array based on the value entered in players like this:

```
public void SetInitialScores()
{
    scores = new int[players];

    for (int i = 0; i < players; i++ )
    {
        scores[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

Here's a Fiddle demonstrating: https://dotnetfiddle.net/JmHsLQ

and the fully modified code:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Game GC = new Game();
        var players = GC.GetNumberPlayers();
        var scores = GC.SetInitialScores();

        Console.WriteLine("You entered {0} players!", players);

        Console.WriteLine("Printing scores");
        foreach (int val in scores)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(val);
        }

    }               
}

public class Game
{
    private int players = 0;
    private int[] scores;
    private string[] playerNames;

    public int Players
    {
        get { return players; }
        set { players = value; ; }
    }

    public int[] Scores
    {
        get { return scores; }
        set { scores = value; }
    }

    public int GetNumberPlayers()
    {
        string playersString;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter number of players");
        playersString = Console.ReadLine();
        Int32.TryParse(playersString, out players);
        return players;
    }

    public int[] SetInitialScores()
    {
        scores = new int[players];

        for (int i = 0; i < players; i++ )
        {
            scores[i] = 0;
        }

        return scores;
    }
}
```